# Custom Pagination

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, pagination, laravel-pagination

I'm following the tutorial here in the docs:

[Custom Presenters](http://laravel.com/docs/pagination#custom-presenters)

But where do I place the Zurb Presenter class in my file system and how do I let Laravel know it exists?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a defined place to put the actual file so you usually put it wherever feels the most natural to you.  I'd probably create a `presenters` folder within your `app` folder and put it in there.

To let Laravel know where it is, there are a couple things you can do.

The first is adding it via composer.  In your `composer.json` file, in the `autoload` `classmap` section, simply add your folder `app/presenters`.  Then you will want to open up your command line, navigate to your project's directory, and run the command `composer dump-autoload`.  Now it should automatically be loaded via composer.

The other solution would be to open up `global.php` in your `app/start` folder and add another entry in the `ClassLoser::addDirectories()` entry pointing to your new folder.

`app_path().'/presenters',`